# Windows Server 2008 network limitations?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, socket, connections, limitations

Please tell me:

Are there some limitations on connection/socket/http in Windows Server 2008 R2 editions family? For example i am pretty sure that some of servers will have 100+ connections (by sockets and http requests) at the same time (simultaneously) from other servers in network. In [this](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx) comparison i found some limitations on "Network Access Connections (IAS)" and "Network Access Connections (RRAS)" but i do not how these limitations will influence on socket/http connections. If these limitations will block for example more then 50+ local network connections from other servers, so i must choose Enterprise edition. Am i right?

Thank you for any advice!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of those figures you link to are relevant to your use case and your use case won't even slightly bother the maximum connections per server, we have some with several thousand constant connections with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: thank you for answer! Could you tell me please what editions do you use for so many connections? is it standard edition?

Comment: We happen to use EE as we use clustering but most services have limits in the multiple thousand even with the cheapest versions.

Answer (score 2):

These figures are not for "connections" they are for the number of windows users making connections.

Windows 2003 had a limitation of 64,000 connections per IP Address.

This has been fixed in Windows 2008, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951764